# Group products using Woocommerce REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm trying to create a grouped products using latest version of Woocommerce REST API.
I managed to create a product with type `grouped` and a few products with type `simple`. But how do I actually group them together?
The `grouped_products` array, which contain IDs of grouped products is read only and `parent_id` property is not what I'm looking for.
Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

The `grouped_products` property is now editable in the WooCommerce REST API v2. It was previously marked as READ ONLY but that only applies to v1 of the REST API. With v2 of the REST API you can create a grouped product and set the `grouped_products` array like this:

```
curl -X POST https://example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/products \
    -u consumer_key:consumer_secret \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -d '{
  "name": "Test grouped product",
  "type": "grouped",
  "grouped_products": [1, 2, 3]
}'
```

where 1, 2 and 3 are the child simple products to be included in the grouped product.